I have function1 and function2 in JS, I want to wait until all animations are finished from function1 then to execute function2
I am new to JS and trying execute function2 after function1 is finished, below are my function that I am using. But with this implementation I see function2 gets executed before function1 is completely finished.
Function1
function repeatPatternColor(pattern) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                const color = pattern[i];
                const singleCol = document.getElementById(color);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    singleCol.classList.add(`${color}-light`);
                }, (i + 1) * delayMileSec);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    singleCol.classList.remove(`${color}-light`);
                }, (i + 2) * delayMileSec);

                console.log(color);
            }, (i + 1) * delayMileSec);
        }
        resolve();
    });
}

Function2
function generateColor() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        disableDivs();
        const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        const id = color[randomNum].id;
        pattern.push(id);
        const singleCol = document.getElementById(id);
        singleCol.classList.add(`${id}-light`);
        setTimeout(function () {
            singleCol.classList.remove(`${id}-light`);
            enableDivs();
        }, 1000);
        console.log("Pattern: " + pattern);
        resolve();
    });
}

Calling Function
async function fnAsync() {
    await repeatPatternColor(pattern);
    await generateColor();
}

let response = fnAsync();


Your statement is not quite true.  Your function1 certainly has completely finished.  It queued up a bunch of callbacks, which will run later, but are independent of function1 itself.  You could have function1 return the total amount of time for the animation, and use a setTimeout to trigger function2.

The first question is why do these functions return Promises. They dont look like they are doing something that requires that. As for your question, it seems that function 1 requires (pattern.length * delayMileSec) time to complete. So put function 2 in a timeout that waits for that long.

Function1 needs to resolve its promise after all the animations complete. It's resolving it when it starts all the timeouts, not after they finish.

Instead of the model you have adopted currently, I would suggest you have a wait function like this:
const wait = time => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time));

then rewrite your "Function 1" using an asynchronous format, an example below:
async function repeatPatternColor(pattern) {
    const promises = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++)
        promises.push((async () => {
            const color = pattern[i];
            const singleCol = document.getElementById(color);

            await wait(delayMileSec);
            singleCol.classList.add(`${color}-light`);

            await wait(delayMileSec);
            singleCol.classList.remove(`${color}-light`);
        })());
    await Promise.all(promises);
}

As you can probably notice, the function is a lot simpler and now truly async! You can try this with your other function too, and as long as you use await wait() and use await for both functions on your fnAsync, it will work the way you want.

not quite the same effect here. Each iteration of i will begin 2 x delayMileSec after the previous - where as in the OP's code it's one delayMileSec and the "animation" is sort of interleaved

You're right! I'll fix it.

Although this isn't as simple, it's doing the same functionality. Hopefully this can still help!

The issue is that you are resolving the promise as soon as the loop completes. However, setTimeout does not stop execution of a loop, therefore the resolve will be called before the first timeout even fires.
Try the following.
The promise variable will hold the last "classList.remove" promise, which you can await after the loop, or simply return it - as shown in the code
the fn async function simplifies the code a little, takes a callback and waits for delayMileSec before resolving. You await when you add the "light" class, but don't await when you remove it. You only await the last "remove" so your next function will be called at the appropriate time


const pattern = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];
const delayMileSec = 1000;
async function repeatPatternColor(pattern) {
    let promise;
    const fn = async (cb) => {
        await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, delayMileSec));
        cb();
    };
    for(let i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
        const color = pattern[i];
        const singleCol = document.getElementById(color);
        await fn(() => singleCol.classList.add(`${color}-light`));
        promise = fn(() => singleCol.classList.remove(`${color}-light`));
    }
    // await promise;
    // or
    return promise;
}
async function fnAsync() {
    await repeatPatternColor(pattern);
    console.log("done");
}
fnAsync();
.x div {
  display: inline-block;
  width:15vw;
  margin: 1em;
  aspect-ratio: 3/1;
}
#red {
  background:#990000;
  &.red-light {
    background: #ff0000;
  }
}
#green {
  background:#008800;
  &.green-light {
    background: #00ff00;
  }
}
#blue {
  background:#000077;
  &.blue-light {
    background: #4444ff;
  }
}
#yellow {
  background:#888800;
  &.yellow-light {
    background: #cccc00;
  }
}
<div class="x">
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="yellow"></div>
</div>



